# Jest fails to import a package while the rest of my typescript code imports it

Tags: typescript, webpack, jestjs, babeljs

Inside a Jest test file, if I do:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

Then `_` gets evaluate to `undefined`.

If, OTOH, I do:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

Then `_` gets evaluated just fine.

My question is how is this possible given that in other parts of my Typescript codebase I am doing `import _ from lodash` without any issues. I am operating under the assumption that Jest uses the same `tsconfig.js` and `babel.config.js` as my bundler, so why do I get this different outcome?

I have a very simple `jest.config.js` configuration obtained from [here](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/intro-1/jest):

```
module.exports = {
    "roots": [
        "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
        "**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)",
        "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)"
    ],
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
    },
}
```

Here's my `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
        "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/react"],
        "compact" : false,
    "plugins": [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
        ]
}
```

And finally my `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,        
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "*": [
            "node_modules/*",
            "src/typings/*",
            "node_modules/@siedlerchr/types-ol-ext/@types/*"
        ]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.staging-typescript.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop is responsible for this.

Comment: @EstusFlask indeed, setting `esModuleInterop` and clearing the Jest cache, did it.